# PHP in binary mode?

Tags: php, binary

Is it possible to convert PHP to binary mode (compile) and run it in all standard web servers?

Comment: What's a "standard web server" ?

Comment: Would this be to (1) try and obfuscate your code to keep it secret, or (2) or to run it on webservers without PHP?  I'm guessing (1)

Comment: Assume that it should run on a typical shared hosting plane where you don't have root access, and have to use Apache or IIS.

Comment: And what exactly is "binary mode (compile)"? byte code or machine code?

Comment: Ah, now I get it. You want to compile your PHP code. I thought you want to compile PHP itself (i.e. the PHP interpreter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various [PHP accelerators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators) that cache the compiled byte code the interpreter produces. Not sure if they will run without the source still on the server though - I've never tried!

Answer (score 1):

[One Facebook developer is working on a compiled form called "Hyper-PHP"](http://gadgetopia.com/post/7038), and it's not even clear if that will be an open system once complete, but no solution exists yet.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Will never be a compiled Language. It will stay as an Interpreted Language.  
[@Matchu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107415/matchu) Facebook is just Promoting their site, so this is just an Promotion action of Facebook

Comment: Huh? Of course Facebook is going to brag about it. Are you saying that they *aren't* working on the ability to compile PHP scripts?

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of tools that will convert your php source to bytecode and allow you to protect your source code. Some of the more popular ones are Zend Guard by Zend and Ion Cube encoder. You will still need their respective loaders installed on the target server for them to function.